# Calculate overlapped time from a range of time using another range of time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a set of time ranges and from that, I want to calculate how many hours and minutes overlapped in a shift/schedule. The shift is from 22:00 to 6:00, here's and example of time ranges.

```
In            Out
04:30         8:30   | output 1.5, 1hr,30mins
20:00         23:00  | output 1hr 
23:00         6:30   | ouput 6hr disregard 30 mins since end of range is 6am
```

I've tried using momentjs and tried some conditions, I got the first and second correctly but im having a problem for the third 1. Anyone help me for some logic or algorithm how im going to calculate the overlapped time only from the range of time shift 22:00 to 06:00. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a **date** information here, it sounds important to compute deltas between hours belonging to different days... doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details forgot to put the date in the sample. Btw I've already solved it. Thanks.